# How do you debug a Terraform AWS provider file provisioner ssh timeout issue?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've added a file provisioner to an aws_launch_configuration resource and am seeing SSH timeouts.

```
1 error(s) occurred:

* module.dev-agooch.module.web.aws_launch_configuration.primary: timeout - last error: dial tcp :22: connect: connection refused
```

I have ensured that the created security group allows inbound ssh traffic.

Here is my relevant configuration:

```
data "template_file" "pg_service_conf" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/pg_service_conf.tpl")}"

  vars {
    db_host = "${var.db_host}"
    db_port = "${var.db_port}"
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "primary" {
  name_prefix             = "${var.cluster_name}"
  image_id                = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type           = "${var.instance_type}"
  security_groups         = ["${aws_security_group.backend.id}"]
  key_name                = "${var.key_name}"

  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              apt-get install nginx -y
              echo "Hello from primary `hostname`" > /var/www/html/index.html
              EOF

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    content               = "${data.template_file.pg_service_conf.rendered}"
    destination           = "/home/admin/.pg_service.conf"
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "primary" {
  name                    = "${var.cluster_name}-primary"
  launch_configuration    = "${aws_launch_configuration.primary.id}"
  availability_zones      = ["${data.aws_availability_zones.all.names}"]
  target_group_arns       = ["${aws_alb_target_group.frontend.arn}"]
  desired_capacity        = 1
  min_size                = 1
  max_size                = 1
}

resource "aws_security_group" "backend" {
  name                    = "${var.cluster_name}-backend-sg"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "backend_allow_http_inbound" {
  type                    = "ingress"
  security_group_id       = "${aws_security_group.backend.id}"
  from_port               = "${local.http_port}"
  to_port                 = "${local.http_port}"
  protocol                = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks             = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "backend_allow_ssh_inbound" {
  type                    = "ingress"
  security_group_id       = "${aws_security_group.backend.id}"
  from_port               = "${local.ssh_port}"
  to_port                 = "${local.ssh_port}"
  protocol                = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks             = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "backend_allow_all_outbound" {
  type                    = "egress"
  security_group_id       = "${aws_security_group.backend.id}"
  from_port               = 0
  to_port                 = 0
  protocol                = "-1"
  cidr_blocks             = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

I'm using Terraform v0.11.7, provider.aws v1.25.0, provider.template v1.0.0 versions.

What is the best way to go about getting more information out of Terraform about the problem?  Is there some gotcha I'm not aware of?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do here? As it is your code is trying to copy a file but you haven't defined where to copy it to with a connection block. Normally you'd connect to an instance that Terraform is spinning up but that's not going to work for an autoscaling group (the API won't give you any details about the instances directly and even if it did it would only be for those initial instances) and a launch configuration is an immutable template that the ASG will use to create instances, you can't copy things to it like that. Instead you should bake an AMI with something like Packer.

Comment: I'm already creating an AMI with packer, but I need to embed the computed host and port of an RDS (aws_db_instance) resource into the .pg_service.conf file, so I want to dynamically provision that file on launch from those computed values.  The same AMI is used in multiple environments, each having their own database host address.

So it's not possible to use a file provisioner with a launch_configuration?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR After looking into it some more, it does indeed look like my approach was misguided.  Will use `user_data` bash script and create the file from it.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I'd generally recommend either something like user data for creation time configuration of instances or something like Consul-Template for run time configuration if things need to be able change during the lifetime of an instance.

Comment: I've added an answer below that uses `userdata` to bootstrap the files in a base64 encoding. This way you can use a userdata block as others have recommended, but you can "copy" scripts/files/config to the server as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and decided to not user file provisioners at all, but to instead leverage `userdata` script to bootstrap base64 encoded strings of the files in the startup script, and then decoding them back into the original text files on the VM's filesystem.

For your case, you can remove the file provisioner and add a one-liner the `userdata` element:

```sh
echo ${base64encode(data.template_file.pg_service_conf.rendered)} | base64 --decode > /home/admin/.pg_service.conf
```

In context of your existing code:

```sh
# ...
  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo ${base64encode(data.template_file.pg_service_conf.rendered)} | base64 --decode > /home/admin/.pg_service.conf
              apt-get install nginx -y
              echo "Hello from primary `hostname`" > /var/www/html/index.html
              EOF
# ...
```

More info: [Deploy local files to instances without using Terraform file provisioners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631004)